# Where are the desktop wallpapers stored for colors & gradients?

Tags: desktop-background

I see the picture wallpapers are stored in `/usr/share/backgrounds` but I want to know where the files are being stored when I select `System Settings > Appearance > Colors & Gradients`.

Where can I get the `.jpg` or `.png` of just the color?

Comment: i don't know if it's a `.jpg` or `.png` files as a programmer if i use image box i will only set a color not image and if you set wallpaper image at end converted to color i don't know if ubuntu convert colors to image !!

Comment: if you really need this image you can edit your question to `you need color | Gradient color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not stored as file anywhere. They're defined in `dconf` database. Specifically these schemas:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/background/color-shading-type

/org/gnome/desktop/background/secondary-color

/org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color
```

If you run in terminal `dconf watch /` and then change to vertical gradient, and then change one of the colors, you will see what schemas get changed:

```
$ dconf watch /
/org/gnome/desktop/background/color-shading-type
  'vertical'
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'none'
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
  ''

/org/gtk/settings/color-chooser/selected-color
  (true, 0.54117647058823526, 0.88627450980392153, 0.20392156862745098, 1.0)

/org/gtk/settings/color-chooser/selected-color
  (true, 0.54117647058823526, 0.88627450980392153, 0.20392156862745098, 1.0)

/org/gtk/settings/color-chooser/selected-color
  (true, 0.44705882352941179, 0.62352941176470589, 0.81176470588235294, 1.0)

/org/gtk/settings/color-chooser/selected-color
  (true, 0.93333333333333335, 0.93333333333333335, 0.92549019607843142, 1.0)

/org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color
  '#eeeeeeeeecec'
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to "save" one of these colored desktops, say for use on Debian?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can always screenshot empty desktop and crop out the top panel though. Or use image editing software to make an image with gradient. That's what i did for my login screen picture